# adding subtitles programmatically to flv movie

Tags: media-player, flv, subtitle

I have got several flv movies on my server. I'd like to enable my users to add subtitles to them on the fly (programmatically).
Points in time and duration of subtitles is determined by admin. He can set it up via panel and it is stored in DB. Each movie can have a few subtitles in different points of time. A user can choose a movie from the DB and add subtitles for it via user panel. The user cann add as many subtitles as previously defined and finally they will appear on the movie at previously defined (by admin) points in time. The main question is how to combine a movie with subtitles added by users - let's say subtitles are being added to DB with user ID and movie ID so that the system can display the movie with subtitles added by specific user. The movies will be dispalyed by providing an unique URL with MovieID and UserID - thus we will see movie with subtitles entered by user with UserID and subtitles will not cover another ones. Still the main problem is how to add subtitles to flv movie dynamically. HTML5 is, I'm affraid the wrong way 'cos some browsers are not ready to it... Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 3rd party flash video player that has support for subtitles.
One of the most popular ones is **JW Player**. Here you can find more info on its captions(subtitles) plugin:
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/addons/captions-plugin/14974/captions-plugin-reference-guide